# Javascript/Typescript call external function from within function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have:

```
 connect(id: string) {
    console.log(id);
    this.connection = this.api.connect(id);
    this.connection.on('open', function () {
      this.testConnect();
    });
  }

testConnect(){

  }
```

I want to be able to call the testConnect function from within the this.connection.on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an arrow function:

```
this.connection.on('open', () => {
  this.testConnect();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

do the following

```
let _that = this;
this.connection.on('open', function () {
  _that.testConnect();
});
```

Why I did this? because `this` in javascript is tied to a function so the callback function has it's own `this` that is totally different from the `class` one!, note that class in typescript is compiled into an function... try the [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to understand what I'm saying